# how to fix Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following and {

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm doing an OLD exame for my next exams and i encountered those problems :

```
**1-** ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "{" when expecting one of the following:


**2-** ORA-06550: line 23, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following:
```

i tried many things like to change the `IF statement` to look for errors type of `( ; '' ) missing` etc but nothing really works

### **Code :**

```
declare

cursor cur is select * from emp where sal > 0 order by sal ;

enreg emp%rowtype;

x number;

i number;

chaine dept.ename%type;

begin 

open cur;

select count ename into x from emp where sal > 0;

i:=0;

loop

fetch cur into enreg;

i:=i+1;

IF i<x/4 THEN 

{

dbms_output.put_line('le nom du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.ename);

dbms_output.put_line('lancien salaire du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.sal);

update emp

set emp.sal = emp.sal+((emp.sal*4)/100);

WHERE emp.sal = enreg.sal;

select dname from dept into chaine where dept.deptno=enreg.deptno;

enreg.sal := emp.sal;

dbms_output.putline('le depart  du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| chaine);

dbms_output.putline('le nouveau salaire du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.sal);

}

elseif i>=x/4 and i<=x/2 then 

{

dbms_output.putline('le nom du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.ename);

dbms_output.putline('lancien salaire du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.sal);

update emp

set emp.sal = emp.sal+((emp.sal*6)/100);

where emp.sal=enreg.sal;

select dname from dept into chaine where dept.deptno=enreg.deptno;

enreg.sal := emp.sal;

dbms_output.put_line('le depart  du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| chaine);

dbms_output.put_line('le nouveau salaire du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.sal);

}

else 

{

dbms_output.put_line('le nom du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.ename);

dbms_output.put_line('lancien salaire du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.sal);

update emp

set emp.sal = emp.sal+((emp.sal*8)/100);

where emp.sal=enreg.sal;

select dname from dept into chaine where dept.deptno=enreg.deptno;

enreg.sal := emp.sal;

dbms_output.putl_ine('le depart  du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| chaine);

dbms_output.put_line('le nouveau salaire du ' || i || 'salairié est '|| enreg.sal);

}

end if ;

exit when cur%notfound;

end loop;

end;
```

### **END CODE**

```
the expected results is to upgrade the salary 
the first 1/4 of salaries have 4% upgrade
the other 1/4 have 6 % 
the rest 8%
in the same time and with one cursor i must display the old value of the sal and the new value  and the name of the person + the department which he is in it
```

- ### **tables are :**

  **emp**
   (

  EMPNO   NUMBER(4,0) No  -   1

  ENAME   VARCHAR2(10)

  JOB VARCHAR2(9) 
  MGR NUMBER(4,0)

  HIREDATE    DATE

  SAL NUMBER(7,2)

  COMM    NUMBER(7,2)

  DEPTNO  NUMBER(2,0)

  )

  **dept** 
  (

  DEPTNO  NUMBER(2,0)

  DNAME   VARCHAR2(14)

  LOC VARCHAR2(13)

  )

Comment: Curly brackets - `{}` - don't mean anything in PL/SQL, you need to use valid syntax and logic constructs. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-B7DD4E62-3ED2-41E9-AAE5-90A78788BB31). You also have a semicolon at the end of the line with `set`, on the line before `where`. The error messages are telling you the lines to look at (though for the second one, the issue is really on the previous line...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This clearly is an assignment so instead of a providing the solution I'll point out errors and where appropriate give you a pointer where to find the an answer, but you will need to build the solution. In the long I think that'll be of greater benefit.

```
select count ename into x from emp where sal > 0;
```

This syntax for this statement is invalid. See [Count function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm).

```
update emp
set emp.sal = emp.sal+((emp.sal*4)/100);
WHERE emp.sal = enreg.sal;
```

These statements taken together also have invalid syntax. It seems you are thinking the semicolon - ; - indicates end of line but it actually indicates end of statement. I image you don't want the first - it is actually valid, but it will update every row in the table.  Without that semicolon only subset of rows would be updated, but that subset would be every matching salary, including those already updated. See [Update within Cursor](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php)
A couple general comments.
Your procedure contains a lot of unnecessary repetition.  3 update statements for the EMP and corresponding selects for the DEPT table. You could instead define a variable for the percentage (calculated as 4,6 or 8) as appropriate then use that variable in a single update. And a step further, you can JOIN DEPT to EMP in the cursor and not then need an independent select for each row you process. Just a way to think about processing sets instead on individual rows.
All in addition to what @AlexPoole has pointed out.